# SQL Server Merge multiple insert on not matched by target

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables for merge , one is **source** and other is **target**. Data in **Source** is the output from **CTE**.

I am trying to insert data into Target but i have two conditions to insert the data in target table.

I am using Merge to update existing data and to insert new row. Target table include historical data.

Status in Source will be either 1 or 2 and status in Target will be either R or S.

Here are the sample of the process that I need to perform.

Below is the data in source and target table and also few condition i need to check.

**Source**

```
| ID    |Name | Cond| Status |            
+-------+-----+-----+--------+
|   1   | A   | XYZ | 1      |
```

**Target**

```
| ID    |Name | Cond| Status |  cdate          
+-------+-----+-----+--------+
|   1   | A   | XYZ | R      | 4/09/2019 4:34:28
```

Condition 1: now If there is some changes on Source data then source.status=2 and if target.id=source.id and target.status='R' then , target need to be updated with source data.

**Source**

```
    | ID    |Name | Cond| Status |            
    +-------+-----+-----+--------+
    |   1   | B   | MNO | 2      |
```

**Target**

```
    | ID    |Name | Cond| Status |   cdate         
    +-------+-----+-----+--------+
    |   1   | B   | MNO | R      | 4/09/2019 4:34:28
```

Condition 2: after execution of one stored procedure, `target.status` is changed to 'S'.

Now if `target.status = 'S'` and `source.status = 2` and `(target.name != source.name or target.cond != source.cond)`, a new row needs to be inserted into target with `target.status` as 'R'.

**Source**

```
    | ID    |Name | Cond| Status |            
    +-------+-----+-----+--------+
    |   1   | B   | MNO | 2      |
```

**Target**

```
    | ID    |Name | Cond| Status |            
    +-------+-----+-----+--------+
    |   1   | A   | XYZ | S      | 4/09/2019 4:34:28
    |   1   | B   | MNO | R      | 6/09/2019 7:34:28
```

To achieve the result I used `MERGE` as below :

```
MERGE table_1 AS TARGET
USING data_from_cte AS SOURCE ON (TARGET.ID = SOURCE.ID AND Target.status = 'R') 

--WHEN RECORDS ARE MATCHED, UPDATE THE RECORDS IF THERE IS ANY CHANGE
WHEN MATCHED AND TARGET.STATUS = 'R' 
    THEN UPDATE 
             SET TARGET.name = SOURCE.name,
                 TARGET.cond = SOURCE.cond,

--WHEN NO RECORDS ARE MATCHED, INSERT THE INCOMING RECORDS FROM SOURCE TABLE TO TARGET TABLE
WHEN MATCHED AND TARGET.STATUS = 'S' AND source.status = 2 
             AND (target.name != source.name OR target.cond != source.cond)
    THEN INSERT (id, name, cond, status) 
         VALUES (SOURCE.ID, SOURCE.name, SOURCE.cond, 'R')

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    THEN INSERT (id, name, cond, status) 
         VALUES (SOURCE.ID, SOURCE.name, SOURCE.cond, 'R');
```

Issue here is: I cannot compare target column and source column in `WHEN MATCHED` condition of `MERGE` statement.

How can I solve this problem using `MERGE` statement or using `IF ... ELSE` statement ?

Comment: We have a serious problem here: what is the key of `target`? Initially, one might think it is `ID` - but you show a case when the target table has two rows with ID 1. So tell me this: if target has both S and R for the same ID, should it still insert another row with R? If yes, we can find a way - but that would lead to more and more R-rows being inserted while you run the query. If no, then I doubt this can be done with merge, as you need to *read* multiple target rows to deduce one resulting row - needing subqueries

Comment: Target table has a created_date column  and id , created_date combined make a primary key . Also if there is R in status of Target , then the row should be updated and if there is S then it need to be inserted . I tried alot but i failed . Could you please help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem pretty close, there. You got a bit confused because you needed to check the existense of an S row with `exists` and you tried to do this through the merge syntax. This can't be done: you can only `INSERT` on `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET`. Try this:

```
;MERGE table_1 AS TARGET
USING data_from_cte AS SOURCE -- (add WHERE source.status = 2 to your CTE)
ON (TARGET.ID = SOURCE.ID AND Target.status = 'R') 

--WHEN RECORDS ARE MATCHED, UPDATE THE RECORDS IF THERE IS ANY CHANGE
WHEN MATCHED AND TARGET.STATUS = 'R' AND operation='update' 
    THEN UPDATE 
             SET TARGET.name = SOURCE.name,
                 TARGET.cond = SOURCE.cond,

--WHEN NO RECORDS ARE MATCHED AND NO SAME S ROW EXISTS, INSERT THE INCOMING RECORDS FROM SOURCE TABLE TO TARGET TABLE
WHEN NOT MATCHED AND not exists(select 1 from table_1 t1 where t1.ID = SOURCE.ID AND t1.status = 'S' and t1.name = source.name and t1.cond = source.cond)
    THEN INSERT (id, name, cond, status) 
         VALUES (SOURCE.ID, SOURCE.name, SOURCE.cond, 'R')
```

The second (`WHEN NOT MATCHED`...) condition is changed, but also don't forget to add a `WHERE source.status = 2` clause to your CTE

Comment: I got a error using this logic  as The identifier 'TARGET.ID' cannot be bound. Only source columns and columns in the clause scope are allowed in the 'WHEN NOT MATCHED' clause of a MERGE statement.

Comment: I did this on the run, I should have removed the `target.` prefix, as this is an independent call to `table1`. I modified the code, try again.